# Segmentation of a single Japanese handwritten word into characters

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, nlp, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I want to segment a handwritten Japanese word into characters. Although I did the segmentation using the projection method, I did not reach an accuracy of more than 70%. I need suggestions and also the path to do the same using other advanced methods.

Comment: For a reliable segmentation, you cannot spare doing simultaneous recognition and/or trying different hypothesis, then validating them. This is because general segmentation algorithms know nothing about the shape of the characters.